In ASP.NET Core 8, setting DefaultSlidingExpiration inside AddDistributedSqlServerCache does not work. Default 1200s still used
When setting DefaultSlidingExpiration inside AddDistributedSqlServerCache, the override is not respected.
builder.Services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    options.DefaultSlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90); <=== NOT RESPECTED
    options.ConnectionString = "my-conn-string"
    options.SchemaName = "my-schema-name"
    options.TableName = "my-table-name"
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    ...
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    ...
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    ...
});


What am I missing?
I'm using the using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect APIs. I must use these APIs, please don't recommend the new Identity API. I need a solution using the approach above.

The solution is to set the session IdleTimeout, which overrides the DefaultSlidingExpiration. See solution posted here.
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90);
});

